# Trying to create loop that fills array using info from another array + hash map

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to prepare data to be used inside of a histogram. I want 2 arrays, one is all the temperatures from my highest and lowest collected temperature. The second array will contain the frequency of each temperature.

`int difference` is the difference from the lowest and highest temp

`Array temp` contains the temperatures collected

`HashMap map` contains the frequencies collected of each temp

`Array tempGaps` contains the temperatures + every other temp that was not collected

`Array finalTemps` contains the frequency of each temp.

The goal I hope to achieve is two arrays, one with all the temperatures, one with the frequencies of each and their index value is what corresponds them to eachother.

```
public void fillGaps() {
    int j = 0;
    tempGaps = new int[difference];
    finalTemps = new int[difference];
    for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
        tempGaps[i] = temp[0] + i;
        if (tempGaps[i] == temp[j]) {
            finalTemps[i] = map.get(new Integer(tempGaps[i]));
            j++;
        } else {
            finalTemps[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}output: https://pastebin.com/nFCZXFyp
```

Output:

```
7 ->1 9 ->1 10 ->1 12 ->1 14 ->2 15 ->1 16 ->1 18 ->2 19 ->1 21 ->1 
TEMP GAPS
7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
FINAL TEMPS
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My finalTemp output stops after 14 degrees - occurs 2 times. It does this after any data set I put in which has a frequency of more than 1. Please help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you need the `j` variable. It seems to make things confusing, especially because the for loop is only a single pass-through. Instead, fetch the value from the map. If null, assign 0, otherwise, assign the value.

```
public void fillGaps() {       
    tempGaps = new int[difference];
    finalTemps = new int[difference];
    for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++) { //navigate through every temperature
        tempGaps[i] = temp[0] + i; //assign the current temperature
        Integer frequency = map.get(new Integer(tempGaps[i])); //fetch the frequency
        finalTemps[i] = frequency == null ? 0 : frequency; //assign 0 if null, otherwise frequency if not null
    }
}
```